# using node --inspect to attach Firebase emulated functions to browser DevTools

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-chrome-devtools, firebase-cli

I'm attempting to use `node --inspect` to attach my `index.js` Firebase functions to chrome devtools for a richer debugging experience than the terminal logs offer.

So far I've met with no success; here's what I've tried:

1. simply running either `firebase serve` and `firebase emulators:start` (but Chrome devtools does not seem to detect these)
2. running `node --inspect` against `functions/index.js`, which serves it on `localhost:9229`, but not in the context of the emulator, which I need for the other services (`hosting`, `firestore`).
3. reading the node docs and this SO post: [Can't debug node.js using Chrome DevTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315159/cant-debug-node-js-using-chrome-devtools)

I'm not sure whether

- (a) I'm missing something basic (highly likely),
- (b) it isn't possible to attach the functions emulator to browser devtools, or
- (c) it's possible, but bugged or not implemented (in which case I'll open a bug/feature request with `firebase-tools`).

Any direction appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was just added in version 7.11.0 of the Firebase CLI (see [release notes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.11.0)). You need to run:

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I get the error `error: unknown option '--inspect-functions'` when running that command. I've also made a question on here as well, I would really appreciate any help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493134/error-unknown-option-inspect-functions-return-when-adding-inspect-functio