# error: unknown option '--inspect-functions' return when adding --inspect-functions to firebase emulators:start

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I cant figure out why when I pass in the option `--inspect-functions` to `firebase emulators:start` I get an error saying `error: unknown option '--inspect-functions'`

But when I run `firebase emulators:start` with any options the emulator runs perfectly, So
I am bit stumped and would appreciate any help.

This is my `functions/package.json`:

```
    {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.3.2",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of the Firebase CLI.  `--inspect-functions` wasn't added until recently in version [7.11.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v7.11.0), so you should update:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Hi Doug, yes thats working now. I'm guessing the problem was that I got mixed up between the local firebase-tools version and the global version. I kept removing and installing the local version installed in functions/package.json, but it was likely to be calling the global version. Thank you very much for your help unfortunately the global & local packages catches me out quite a bit, as the version I see in package.json is the version I think I have.